# Forward Teams chat between self and personA to another personB

Tags: microsoft-teams, forwarding, chat

Having a standard chat between myself and personA.  In another standard chat with personB, inform B of that chat's contents.

PersonB asks to be forwarded that chat, as if it were an email chain.

Is there any way to do this? In a good format? Copy/paste will get the content but it's formatted ugly and hard to read.

Also would rather not a screen shot since that can't be text searched.

Comment: Using [this method](https://www.process.st/how-to/print-microsoft-teams-chat/) you could print the chat to a PDF. Would that be a solution?

Comment: While in an enterprise environment Teams does store its chat history in a folder inside the user's mailbox database, this folder is not accessible from within either Outlook or OWA, and so there is not a way to forward the messages "natively" within Outlook. Copying, screenshotting, or printing the chats are the best ways to export the content into an email for forwarding.

Comment: @harrymc that's essentially what I did but it doesn't look good by default. I had to spend extra time formatting it for readability. Compare with an email you click a couple buttons and the person has all the info requested; takes a user 5 seconds. Hoping for a similarly speedy solution with Teams